# How to divide array in parts (without using multidimensional arrays) with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, loops

I need to put content in a `jquery` slider and for the slider each slide is a `<li>` element and I have to put a list of products within that slide, but it also must automatically create a new slide when it's full.

Now I've decided that I'm going to put 4 elements in a boundry of 1 slide so after 4 elements, the php loop must create a new slide. How can I do that? It looks somewhat like this:

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "
    <li>
        $r['title']
    <li>";
}
```

but of course, this code creates a new slide everytime it returns the result, which isn't what I want.

Comment: When interpolating array items you need to wrap it in curly braces, like: `"...{$r['title']}..."`

Comment: what is the HTML of the slider?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
  <?php 
$count=4;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
if($count % 4==0)
{ 
    echo "<li>";
}
echo $r['title']; 
if($count % 4 ==3)
{ 
    echo "</li>";
} 
$count++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$i = 1;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if($i%4==0) echo "<li>";
    echo $r['title'];
    if($i%4==3) echo "</li>";
    $i++;
};
```

Comment: Why? Would you care to elaborate on this and tell me why you downvoted my answer? Maybe I didn't get the question right.

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer now.