# How to get data from database depending on the screen size?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, responsive-design

I need to create a responsive information slider and for each slide, depending on the size of the screen, there would be a different ammount of information, but as far as I know - neither PHP nor MySQL allow me to select data based on screen size, so how could I make this happen?

I tried using JavaScript, but so far with not that much success, my idea was that I could use JS to detect screen size and based no that somehow send that info to PHP which could then adjust the slider accordingly, but could you show me a snippet of code on how to do that, please?

**Edit:** I need it in combination with this: [How to divide array in parts (without using multidimensional arrays) with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939010/how-to-divide-array-in-parts-without-using-multidimensional-arrays-with-php/28940425)

So the slider works as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>content for slide 1</li>
  <li>content for slide 2</li>
  <li>content for slide 3</li>
</ul>
```

and I cannot use jquery to hide something, it has to fit as needed for the contents respective slide.

Comment: PHP is executed serverside, as you most likely know. Hence there is no way it can know the screen size. Styling must be done after the php code is executed using css/js. You can send this information to a php-file using ajax, but this will not be able to modifiy anything existing

Comment: are you looking for a responsive slider?, if so, i think this has nothing to do with the data fetched from database

Comment: Yes, resposive design is usually done with CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp This is NOT Javascript. You can use Javascript to detect screen size and send it to the server using Ajax, then you CAN change the content of your page, which is different from what Shaeldon said.

Comment: im a bit confused, what kind of datas do you fetch that should be restricted by the unit's screen size?

Comment: Kelvin Barsana is correct, you can just hide/show the data's you've fetched when the user reach certain screen size thru jQuery.

Comment: do  you already have a template/slider for this?

Comment: @KelvinBarsana yes, I'm using it right now and I need different ammount of information extracted for each slide.

Comment: do you mean different length of information for each slide?

Comment: @KelvinBarsana yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: you want to get the whole data and make each set of data fit for each slide by resizing it depending on its length?

Answer (score 0):

As all the comments say, it's not possible.

PHP is executed on the server. The server doesn't know about the screen size. There are ways to guess it.

There's the `WURFL` and `Tera-WURFL` Project (http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.tera-wurfl.com/explore/) that are comparing the user agent against a huge database and if found return you the screen size of the device. This of course only works for mobile phones and tablets, not for Laptop/Desktops!

Another thing (that I wouldn't advice you to do!) would be to store the screen size in a PHP Session or Cookie, that get's updated by an AJAX call from Javascript. As I said, I strongly advice you not to do this!

You could build a `Mobile First` Website, meaning it basically on loads the necessary stuff for the mobile format and loads every thing else by AJAX, after the page has loaded. You could do that but this get's pretty messy, very quick.

I would advice you to just load all the data you need from the database (if you are concerned about the speed, just use some caching, I use this class in a few projects: https://github.com/khoaofgod/phpfastcache/) and either hide/show it by media queries in CSS (https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or just have a Javascript to render different stuff for different screen sizes (AngularJS is pretty good in doing that https://angularjs.org/)

I usually use the CSS media queries approach combined with some caching on PHP side.

About the dividing of arrays stuff, I'm pretty sure you can do this with some CSS magik! take a look at `:nth-child` https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the data for maximum screen size and use CSS to hide data which should not be displayed. You could use mediaqueries for that matter.